# How to call a visualforce page from a custom button?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Inquery__c" 
           recordSetVar="accvar" 
           contentType="text/csv#filename.csv">

    "First Name","Last Name","Email","Qualification"

    <apex:repeat value="{!accvar}" var="a">
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(a.Download__c)}">
            {!a.First_Name__c}, {!a.Last_Name__c}, {!a.Email__c}, {!a.Quilification__c}
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

That downloads all the records in a CSV file,
That have the check box field Download__c unchecked.

How can I call this VF from a custom button on the Inquery__c custom object?

When I choose the Content Source as Visualforce Page,
No content is available!

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a javascript for that:

`window.location = 'apex/YourVisualforcePage';`

This is my example of the button:

[image]

And the visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.CustomerPriority__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the result page:

[image]

And here is an screenshot of the account page and the result of the click on the button:

[image]

Now add the button to the object page layout. Go to some of the object records page, find a lind called `Edit Layout` and click on it:

[image]

Now drag your button to the page and drop it in to the `Custom buttons` area, then save the layout:

[image]

Comment: What's the best practice for doing this from LEX, now that the window object is taken away and OnClick JS buttons are disabled?

Comment: Yea this answer is only applicable to Salesforce Classic not LEX

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in Lightning experience you can do in this way.

1) Create a VF page

Download

2) Create a New Button or Link as Detail Page button , Content source as the above VF page.

3) And add the button to the custom button to the Page Layout