# Create a button in a custom object home

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

The custom object home is there anyway to put a new button in that page layout. Or modify that page layout. Or use VF and emulate that page layout exactly, because i am trying to create a custom object that will flow through a set of prev and next steps. The custom object home's only buttons are new or Go, and i am trying to put a custom link in there so i can help them navigate the next and prev pages.

Comment: i think you are trying to create wizard model where you want to navigate back and forth. you might be interested in these links http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm

Comment: Check this out, maybe it can help you: [How to call a visualforce page from a custom button](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/how-to-call-a-visualforce-page-from-a-custom-button/12833#12833)

Comment: thanks for the input, my employer wants to be able to modify the custom object home, and doesn't want me using VF. Which i explained wasn't feasible but insisted it was. So i am just trying to add a link or button in the custom object home so that i can add a button and that would be that, but instead i can use JS and pop up a window instead, which should appease him.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the buttons **New** and **Go** that you've mentioned, I assume you intend to add new button to the custom objects list view page. On the custom object setup page (Setup > Create > Objects > Your Custom Object), navigate to section titled **Buttons, Links, and Actions** and click **[New Button or Link]** button, in order to create new button of **List Button** Display Type. Select either **URL** or **VisualForce Page** as the behavior of the button (note: in order for a VF page to be selectable, you must specify Your_Custom_Object__c as default controller for the VF page).

Once you have the button prepared, navigate to **Search Layouts** section on the same custom object setup page, and select the list layout to edit (typically named "*Your Custom Object List View*") and select to add custom buttons. From the list of custom buttons select your newly created button and save changes to the layout.

Comment: Great thanks, It looks as though i will be using this method. Is there anyway to send information through a button using js. I think a combination of a ActionCommand and param will enable me to send relative information to my controller, but it is a custom object page that is created by Salesforce.

Comment: Sure you can send info using js - when creating the button, specify "Execute JavaScript" as the button's behavior. Then, in the textarea at the bottom of the configuration screen, you could use js to fetch and evaluate any sort of values stored on the client, and finally make a redirect (by window.location set to literal string of the relative path of your custom VF page, e.g. "/apex/MyCustomObjectBtnClickHandlePage") with js arguments added to the URL. Hope it's clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two solutions.  Try looking into Visual Flow.  This is all setup and should give you the customization you need.  If more customization is needed, you can actually put it in a VF page.

Also, you can use fieldSets to dynamically render a fields on a page.  Simply get a list of the items in a field set, and you can loop over them to grab the field name of whatever associate object you need.