# Create VF page with data from multiple objects

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to create a popup window as an action button in my Opportunity layout that will show details from my `Opportunity` and its related `Contacts` and `Clients`. I imagine this must be done via Visualforce. Could someone help me do this or point me in the redirection on how I can achieve this?

I'd imagine this would invole a Visualforce page and an apex class.

Comment: Yes it would involve that but typically questions here are for something specific.  You can use a Javascript button on the default layout to popup the VF page.  a VF page and apex class can do the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create one visualforce page that uses an Opportunity as [standard controller](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std.htm):

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity" columns="1">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputText value="Contacts"/>
            <apex:pageBlockTable title="Contacts" 
                                 value="{!Opportunity.Contacts__r}" var="contact">
                <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Because the page uses a the standard controller i dont need to create any apex controller, salesforce will do it for me. You can access assotiated object (Opportunity) and all related objects (in this example Contacts).

Then you will need to create a new custom button for the Opportunity object that will open this page in a popup. Then add this button to the Opportunity layout ([here you can learn how to create cutom buttons and add them to the layout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/how-to-call-a-visualforce-page-from-a-custom-button/12833#12833)). Use following javascript code in your custom button:

```
popup = window.open("apex/OppPopup?id={!Opportunity.Id}", "newPopup", "width=620,height=390, scrollbars=no, location=no"); 
popup.moveTo(((screen.width-620)/2),((screen.height-390)/2)); 
popup.focus();
```

Where `OppPopup` is the name of my visualforce page.

The button will then look like this:

[image]

By clicking on the button a new popup window appears (`OppPopup` page):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. One thing I noticed was that a parameter was passed in the URL, but its not mentioned of in the VisualForce page (or that I can see). Can I pass multiple parameters here? Would it be possible to also pass this data on screen to other functions? e.g. another page or apex class?

Comment: @Imran This is a point of the standard controller. You need to pass only one record id, then you can access all fields and all child relationships on the visualforce page. You can for sure create an apex extension for the standard controller if you need more functionallity then a standard controller can give.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to start with this chapter in the manual:

- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller.htm

It comes with some examples and is not too hard to understand. But you have to get familiar  with the basic concepts of Visualforce and Apex.

If you want to combine the data as you asked, it depends very much on what you want to achieve in particular. Have a look at:

- https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_detail.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_custom_list_controller.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm